# React Router issues

Tags: reactjs, server, react-router

I'm learning react-router, but I don't use Node as server. What I'm doing is to put all of files in /htdocs of XAMPP on MacOSX and previously all of the code was fine until I add the react router. The error on console is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined.

The sample code as follow:

```
//app.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './component/App.jsx';
import Home from './component/Home.jsx';
import Repos from './component/Repos.jsx';
import About from './component/About.jsx';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/repos/:name" component={Repos} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is my webpack config

```
var config = {
    entry: './index.jsx',
    output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'index.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
             {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
        }
    ]
}
}
module.exports = config;
```

There is no problem when I render any of single component I imported, just simple static component, I show one of these here:

```
//Home.jsx
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => (
  <div>Home</div>
);
export default Home;
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your  to:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
```

Worked for me.